# Time taken for a rocket to travel upwards

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, acceleration, differentiation, differential-equations, rocket-science

My doubt is a rather silly, simple one but i cant seem to understand what's wrong.

Let's assume a rocket is moving up with a constant acceleration of a, is moving strictly vertically(no gravity turns, etc.) and reaches a height h. Obviously the time taken should be
$t=\sqrt{\frac{2h}{a-g}}$(net acceleration is a - g). But in this case h has a bigger significant value, so that gravity also changes with height. I tried to do the following(which obviously is false):
$$\frac{d^2s}{dt^2}=(a-g(\frac{R}{R+ds})^2)$$
I've tried the binomial expansion aswell:
$$\frac{d^2s}{dt^2}=(a-g(1-2\frac{ds}{R}))$$
The problem here is i cant integrate the above integral. Where did i go wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you formulated your question confused me a bit. I think that you trying to consider the case where there a constant external **force** and not a constant acceleration. If that's the case here is my solution.

As you suggested if the value of $h$ is rather large then we must make use of the full formula describing gravitational force,
\begin{equation}
F_g=G\frac{m M}{(R+h)^2},
\end{equation}
where $R$ is the radius of the earth and $M$ is the mass of the earth. On top of that we also assume that there is a constant external force $F$ pushing the rocket upward. Then Newton's equation is written as
\begin{equation}
m \frac{d^2 h}{dt^2} = F - G\frac{m M}{(R+h)^2}.
\end{equation}
Now you can try to solve the equation directly but to me it seems more advantageous to take a secondary route and use **conservation of energy**. Recall that the variation of total energy is equal to the work done by the external forces (in this case $F$), and that the gravitational force admits a potential energy given by $U=- G(m M)/(R+h)$. Then we may write
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\Delta E=& W_{est} = F \Delta h \\
\Delta U +& \Delta K = F \Delta h \\
- G\frac{m M}{R+h} + G\frac{m M}{R+h_0} &+ \frac{1}{2} m v^2 - \frac{1}{2} m v_0^2= F (h-h_0).
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Now we fix the initial conditions as $v_0=0, h_0=0$ and the equation simplifies to ($v= dh/dt$)
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2} m \biggl(\frac{dh}{dt}\biggl)^2= Fh+ G\frac{m M}{R+h}- G\frac{m M}{R} \rightarrow \\
\rightarrow \frac{dh}{dt}=\sqrt{\frac{2}{m} \biggl(Fh+ G\frac{m M}{R+h}-G\frac{mM}{R}\biggl)}.
\end{equation}
In the last equation we can use separation of variables and perform an integral in $h$ (probably using Mathematica) to get the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer and yes i actually meant constant force srry for confusion. I did understand the method of conservation of energy, the way how you did it, but i still am stuck and unable to understand, how there ,at the demoninators(R+h of both the equations), have you put R+h . Shouldnt it be R+dh since the potential energy or the gravitational attraction is minutely increasing with infinitely small values of h.

Comment: Well in this case I am evaluating a finite potential energy difference $\Delta U=U(h)-U(h_0=0)$, there is no infinitesimal variation. Note also that if you want to evaluate a infinitesimal energy variation the correct formula would be \begin{equation} dU= \frac{dU}{dh} dh= -F_{grav} dh \end{equation}where i used the fact that $F_{grav}=- \frac{dU}{dh}$